# postDelayed Handler doesn't stop

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

what I need is when competition.isTimerStarted turns false this runnable should start buttonsProcedure() once and stop itself
But this doesn't happen - buttonsProcedure() is being called forever and runnable doesn't stop.

```
 timerRun=new Runnable()
            {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {

                     timerTVmainmenue.setText(competition.getTimerTime());
                     if (!competition.isTimerStarted) {thandler.removeCallbacks(timerRun);Log.d("MyLog","timerrun is blame for infinite butproc");buttonsProcedure();}
                thandler.postDelayed(timerRun, 243); //looping this for every 243 ms
                 }
            };
```

how can I stop it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        timerRun=new Runnable()
        {
             @Override
             public void run() {

                 timerTVmainmenue.setText(competition.getTimerTime());
                 if (!competition.isTimerStarted){
                thandler.removeCallbacks(this);
                Log.d("MyLog","timerrun is blame for infinite butproc");
                 buttonsProcedure();
                 return;
             }
            thandler.postDelayed(this, 243); //looping this for every 243 ms
             }
        };
```

you have to add   `return` inside the if condition or use the `if-else` construct

Comment: wow thanks! I can accept answer in 7 minutes for some reason. Can you explain to me this issue? why return saves this situation?

Comment: well there is not much to explain.. the next instruction after the closing bracket  of the if clause is postDelayed. So you remove it the runnable inside the if clause and repost it just after the if block. With the return you are breaking the normal flow of the code

Comment: That return thing did the trick.. I don't care if its late or something, but I have to say thank you, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Get it out of the runnable. What you are doing is removing callbacks and then (next line) -- posting it again. If you change the places you will reach your desired effect, but at the cost of always setting it up and removing callbacks. So just remove callbacks from somewhere else in your code.